# Does using .kv file slow the kivy program?

Tags: python, kivy

As far as I know, there are three ways of using kivy.

1. Use it in Python only.
2. Use .kv format in Python using `Builder.load_string()`.
3. Use .kv files.

I've recently found that using an kivy instance that is initialized in Python sometimes works faster than the one that is intialized in `.kv`.

For example,

```
class Root(BoxLayout):
    self.a = SomeWidget()
    self.add_widget(self.a)

    def some_function(self):
        self.a.do_something() # <-- This line of the codes
```

tends to be faster than

```
Builder.load_string('''
Root:
    SomeWidget:
        id: a
''')

class Root(BoxLayout):
    def some_function(self):
        self.ids.a.do_something() # <-- This line of the codes
```

*(Only considering the performance between `self.a.do_something()` and `self.ids.a.do_something()`)*

What I am thinking is that, it seems to me that kivy main loop is working asynchronous and python works synchronous, so referencing to `.kv` can be delayed until main loop completes a cycle. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Does it have a difference in performance this way?

Also, is there any difference between using `Builder.load_string()` and `.kv` files in terms of performance and functionality?

Comment: I think it should be obvious that your second code sample will be slower, because it is doing a `Builder.load_string()` that the first code is not doing. Also, the second code is doing a dictionary lookup (`self.ids.a`) that the first is not. However, the `Builder.load_string()` is typically only done once at the start of an app, so shouldn't affect performance after that.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yes, I am talking about the difference between `a.do_something()` and `self.ids.a.do_something()` without considering the time doing `Builder.load_string()`. It seems it has a difference in my system. So I've copied every interactive kivy object to python code and it seems to get faster.

Comment: Also, does Builder.load_string() slower than using a seperate `.kv` file? My kivy program takes 3 minutes to boot in my embedded system, so I wish to reduce the time.